# Trying to return "basenames" of filenames with and without version tags

Tags: python, regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

I've been trying to write a regex that will return the base names of versioned files but also return the base name of a non-versioned file in the same list.

```
import re

file_list = [
    "ThisFile_v01.ext",
    "ThisFile_v02.ext",
    "ThatFile_v01.ext",
    "ThatFile_v02.ext",
    "NonVersionedFile.ext",
    "Non_VersionedFile.ext",
]

r = re.compile(r"^(?P<basename>.*(?!_v))(?P<version>_v\d+\.)?(?(version).*$|\..*$)")
for f in file_list:
    match = r.match(f)
    print(match.group('basename'))
```

I'm trying to return a list like this:

```
ThisFile
ThisFile
ThatFile
ThatFile
NonVersionedFile
Non_VersionedFile
```

I'm currently getting this:

```
ThisFile_v01
ThisFile_v02
ThatFile_v01
ThatFile_v02
NonVersionedFile
Non_VersionedFile
```

I'm probably over thinking it but I've been thru a lot of iterations and I can't seem to figure this one out. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your regex gives me a slight headache. I suppose there's a conflict between all the optional parts.

Why not just remove the `v_xxx` (optional) & extension using `sub`?

```
r = re.compile("(_v\d+)?(\..*)")
for f in file_list:
    print(r.sub("",f))
```

this is simpler and gives me:

```
ThisFile
ThisFile
ThatFile
ThatFile
NonVersionedFile
Non_VersionedFile
```

Comment: Yep, I was totally over thinking it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Super simple change to your regex fixes your problem. The underlying issue with your regex was that you were using "greedy" calls. If you tell them to be "non-greedy" you'll get your desired output.

`r = re.compile(r"^(?P<basename>.*?)(?P<version>_v[0-9]+)?\.ext")`

The above regex forces the basename search to be minimal (the `?` at the end of the group is what causes that) meaning the `.*` will stop searching as soon as it can instead of gobbling up every character it can get its hands on.